# custom OnConflictStrategy using Room DB

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I'd like to set my own conflict columns not default primary key (just an auto increment integer in my case). So my table is:

```
@Entity(tableName = "users_tab")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int,
    var str1: String,
    var str2: String,
    var str3: String
)

@Dao
interface UserDAO {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(users: List<User>)

}
```

I'd like to `REPLACE` when `User` has same `str1` and `str2` how should I modify my `Insert` adnotation?

Comment: AFAIK, Room only supports SQLite's conflict strategies. My guess is that you will need to create a separate `@Transaction` function that queries the database to see if there is a conflict before inserting

Comment: @CommonsWare I guess it will be faster to delete+insert then query DB and decide to insert or not, isn't it?

Comment: I have not tested that scenario. I would be surprised if query+insert is dramatically slower, and it might be quite a bit faster (e.g., cascade deletes getting triggered).